# JProfiler snapshot is slow

Tags: jprofiler

Creating offline snapshot with jpcontroller utility freezes the application for about 5-10 seconds. By the way, the same behavior I can see if you make heap dump. Maybe there is possibility to switch it off.

Does any one know how to make snapshoting faster?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a heap snapshot requires freezing the JVM until all objects on the heap have been enumerated. This takes progressively longer the larger the heap is.

Comment: Is it possible to gather only method statistics offline and view it later? I don't need heap dump at all.

Comment: Unless you explicitly request it from jpcontroller, it does not take a heap dump. Once you have taken a heap dump, it gets saved to the snapshot every time. There's no way to delete a heap dump in a running session.

Comment: Making snapshot it self takes a lot of time. Just start jpcontroller. No heap dumps. No thraed dumps. No any dumps. No anything. And each time you call 'save snapshot' it freezes JVM for about 10 seconds. I want it to be faster and looking for a solution.

Comment: What are you recording and how large are the resulting snapshots?

Comment: We record only 'CPU data' and 'Thread data'. Sampling. Filtering is off.  Snapshot is ~100MB in average.